# C - Integer to Array Index

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

Ideally, I would like to be able to have 2 arrays.  The first one would be an array of integers, like:
    n[0] = 30000;
    n[1] = 650;
    n[2] = 3;
...up to around 50 values or so.

And I need to find the fastest(most efficient, and hopefully capable of using registered variables) to be able to get the index from array of values using a value, like:
    x[30000] = 0;
    x[650] = 1;
    x[3] = 2;

This seems like it would be an associative array (which I would need another lib for), but it seems like such a simple thing that I cannot believe the capabilities aren't already there.  I will only be working with 50 values or so, so making an array of 30001 in this case, just to be able to map one integer to another, would be ridiculous.

Can anyone tell me the best way to map one int to another int, keeping in mind there will be no more than 50, and not loop-checking each one for a match?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you really don't want the 30000-element inverse array, then you're pretty much stuck with a hashtable as you suspected. Simple integer hashes are quite efficient and good.

Comment: The fastest is the array of 30001. You could also do it with a hash table, a balanced binary search tree, or an array of structs using a binary search. But I think that you'd just be wasting development time. Loop checking an array with 50 entries is so fast, that the effort to optimize it is almost certainly a waste.

Comment: You have to consider what are the highest possible value that can be stored in your first array, because that would be the size of your second array.

Comment: If your values are compile-time constants, you could use a long `switch` and have the compiler figure out the most efficient lookup strategy for you.

Comment: I agree with all the "for those few values, not worth the effort" comments. However, if you have more values or over a greater range of subscripts, you might try using a sparse file.

Comment: The values are not available during compilation. The most important thing in the world for this is the lookup speed. Do you think an inverse array would be faster, even if it could be 1,000,000 instead of 30,000? If it made it up to the 1,000,000 mark, a conditional doesn't seem efficient enough. Sorry, I forgot to say that 30,000 could also be 30,000,000.